# What non-bird datasets are available (No labels needed)

Tags: dataset

What I found so far was either bird datasets (xeno-canto or all except the bees from [the bioacoustics dataset page](https://bioacousticsdatasets.weebly.com/)) or [bees](https://qmro.qmul.ac.uk/xmlui/handle/123456789/55776) (also on [the bioacoustics dataset page](https://bioacousticsdatasets.weebly.com/)). I know there is the [tierstimmenarchiv](https://www.museumfuernaturkunde.berlin/en/science/animal-sound-archive) by the Museum für Naturkunde Berlin, but this is not downloadable as a whole. I am not looking for curated or labeled datasets, just for a diverse set of audio files.

I also looked through kaggle without much success.

Comment: Hi Julian. Are marine sound datasets of interest for your search, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If what you want is diversity more than "quality" (e.g. taxonomic precision), you can look at AudioSet (a generic sound dataset from Youtube). For example [the AudioSet "animal" tag contains over 40,000 annotated sound clips](https://research.google.com/audioset/ontology/animal.html), though approx half of those are cats and dogs.
- There are large marine sound datasets, e.g. this [DCLDE dataset](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/ore/dclde/dataset/) or [DOCC10](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9207085)
- [bio.acousti.ca](https://bio.acousti.ca/) contains diverse animal sound recordings, across many taxa, and taxonomically organised. It certainly covers mammal and insect sounds, for example. I believe the data is downloadable in bulk, though I'm not 100% sure of the process.
- Through [GBIF](https://www.gbif.org/) you can search for occurrences with audio media. To give an arbitrary example, [a GBIF search for *Surica suricatta*](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search?media_type=Sound&taxon_key=2434126) currently shows 4 results, all via Tierstimmenarchiv. It should, I think, be possible to use GBIF's API to automatically download files.

I look forward to reading other people's suggestions of data sources too!

Comment: Perfect, thanks, Dan!

Answer (score 3):

[LILA BC](https://lila.science/) is a website that hosts biological datasets with the goal of making them easier to find and access for machine learning researchers/practitioners. Right now it's entirely image datasets, but they have a list of other [bioacoustic datasets](https://lila.science/otherdatasets#bioacoustics). Looks like it is mostly marine mammals and birds.

Comment: Cool project, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[**Macaulay Library**](https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/about/) has audio recordings of hundreds of non-avian species that researchers can request free of charge. Archives include, for example:

- 293  [humpback whale (Megaptera novaeangliae)](https://search.macaulaylibrary.org/catalog?mediaType=audio&searchField=animals&taxonCode=t-11028617) recordings
- 74 [squirrel treefrog (Dryophytes squirellus)](https://search.macaulaylibrary.org/catalog?mediaType=audio&searchField=animals&taxonCode=t-11130854) recordings
- 24 [oyster toadfish (Opsanus tau)](https://search.macaulaylibrary.org/catalog?searchField=animals&mediaType=audio&taxonCode=t-10869486) recordings
- 160 [common true katydid (Pterophylla camellifolia)](https://search.macaulaylibrary.org/catalog?searchField=animals&mediaType=audio&taxonCode=t-11876111) recordings

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check dosits.org for a good database of underwater sounds from a good variety of taxa.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your answer and the link. Do you know if it is possible to download the whole archive? I was unable to find a way to download the sounds other than scrapping it.