# Is there a shared open access Bioacoustics platform?

Tags: recording, data-storage, dataset, data, field-recordings

I am searching for a Bioacoustics platform where I can download and upload free bioacoustic data.

It would have to be open data that can be shared and used freely for other venues such as filmmakers.

I am not looking for random datasets, this should be a platform.

Comment: Welcome @WMRamadan. This question potentially has answers on platforms here https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/1078/131?

Comment: @Thejasvi as I have mentioned I am looking for a platform not datasets and nothing specific to one subject but a range of subjects.

Comment: Would you then please define what you mean by platform (characteristics)?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what defines a platform

Comment: Look at this page and scroll down to **Bioacoustics online repositories** - is that what you're looking for? https://bioacousticsdatasets.weebly.com/

Answer (score 6):

[Macaulay library](https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/) would probably be your best best. Though you have to submit a request to actually download the file. You can view the spectrogram/listen to the call through the platform though. I've had good success with these requests though.

But there are others:
[Xeno-Canto](https://xeno-canto.org/) (birds only),
[eBird](https://ebird.org/home),
[iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/projects/audio-observations-from-around-the-world),
[Merlin SoundID](https://merlin.allaboutbirds.org/),
[LILA BC](https://lila.science/) (machine-learning datasets).

And some are more for viewing audio files but I'm not sure how easy it would be to upload to them. E.g.,
[Discovery of Sound in the Sea](https://dosits.org/galleries/audio-gallery/) (DOSITS; marine animals),
[FishSounds](https://fishsounds.net/index.js),
[Watkins Marine Mammal Sound Database](https://cis.whoi.edu/science/B/whalesounds/index.cfm),

Comment: By the way, Xeno Canto also has insect sounds (new this year) - it is broadening its scope

Comment: oooo thats exciting!

Comment: FishSounds will be making it easier for users to upload sound files to the website with a planned update sometime in the next 6 months, but for now, you have to contact the FishSounds team directly at fishsoundscontact@gmail.com to upload any sound files. All of the FishSounds sounds and data are also for non-commercial use with attribution and would require additional permissions for any commercial use.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 6):

Another option, albeit not specific to bioacoustics, is [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/discover). I've seen more and more researchers, including the group I work with at [NOAA Southwest Fisheries Science Center](https://soundcloud.com/southwestacousticecology) and also the [Gray's Reef Sanctuary](https://soundcloud.com/graysreef) using SoundCloud as a repository. The search function works fairly well and there are options to download files.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in marine sounds, the SANCTSOUND portal is what you want to explore. You can't upload sounds there, but there are some nice sounds of animals as well as anthropogenic sounds that comes from 4 years of recordings in the MPA across USA. The portal is nicely organized and easy to access.

https://sanctsound.ioos.us/sounds.html#atlantic-midshipman-florida-keys

You can download the sounds, as the portal is mentioned to be free access for people. You can also enquire them, if you have a project in mind, and ask if you can have access to certain kind of sounds. I've followed the conference where they presented the project, results and portal and found to be a large sample of great sounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find some recordings on the French national museum sound library. However, the downloads are in mp3 you might want to contact them for original wave files. https://sonotheque.mnhn.fr/?lang=en_En

Answer (score 1):

I know of bioacoustics libraries (Macaulay - https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/; TierstimmenArchiv - https://www.tierstimmenarchiv.de/webinterface/contents/index.php; British Library - https://sounds.bl.uk/Environment; Borror Laboratory - https://mbd-db.osu.edu/) and the rules vary.

This is a really cool idea though.